# Why is the output different from what expected

Tags: java

## Code

```
import java.util.*;
class TestCollection12 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        PriorityQueue<String> queue = new PriorityQueue<String>();
        queue.add("Amit");
        queue.add("Vijay");
        queue.add("Karan");
        queue.add("Jai");
        queue.add("Rahul");

        System.out.println("head:"+queue.element());
        System.out.println("head:"+queue.peek());

        System.out.println("iterating the queue elements:");
        Iterator itr=queue.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }

        queue.remove();
        queue.poll();

        System.out.println("after removing two elements:");
        Iterator<String> itr2=queue.iterator();
        while (itr2.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(itr2.next());
        }
    }
}
```

## Expected

```
amit amit amit vijay karan jai rahul
karan jai rahul
```

Comment: Please indent your code and edit your question to contain the output.

Comment: It is great that your are showing your code, but please also add some text (not in the question title) explaining what your are trying to achieve and how it is going wrong.  Also, your code seems to have spurious `<br>` tags in it and could maybe be made more readable by using indentation?

Answer (score 0):

From the doc:
         PriorityQueue with the default initial capacity (11) that orders its elements according to their natural ordering.
element() & peek returns the head of the queue.
After the first iteration

```
Amit
Jai
Karan
Vijay
Rahul
```

remove() & poll() -> removes the head of the queue.
After second iteration the output will be

```
Karan
Rahul
Vijay
```

It works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

It is all about priorty queues.
In priority queue it is stored in array like data structure. For your example it is stored as;

```
[0] "Amit"
[1] "Jai"
[2] "Karan"
[3] "Vijay" 
[4] "Rahul"
```

Always the zero indexed element is the top element, and when you peek or poll the first one is polled, and the array is changed according to this.

After your first remove call, the array change as below.

```
[0] "Jai"   
[1] "Rahul" 
[2] "Karan" 
[3] "Vijay"
```

And again after calling poll;

```
[0] "Karan" 
[1] "Rahul" 
[2] "Vijay"
```

As a summary the top element is always the smallest (or the greatest) one. After popping the order changes. You can read the details on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue

Comment: Ugur Basak@i agree wid you but how you have done indexing.first time you put the"rahul" at the bottom why??

Comment: Rakesh, actually I got this values using variables view from Eclipse. 
Also this animation can help you to see how things happen in the backend https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/Heap.html With each insertion the max/min value tries to reach to the top index, by swapping values. And each swap occurs by reaching the next half of the array. For Rahul, Rahul is added to the 5th index and we compare it with 2nd index, which is smaller than Rahul and we do not a swap operation. But if it is smaller than the 2nd one, then we need to swap it also.

Comment: Yes Rakesh. You have two choices, if you are using it as a maxheap the top one will be the max value, otherwise it will be the minimum value. It helps you to retrive the top values in O(1) time. For more details also you can check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap